# Why return of get() function in laravel is not array when check with is_array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am just very new to laravel and today I have run some code and get stuck at this code.

```
    $topic = topic::where('id', $id)->get();
    if(is_array($topic)){
        echo 'yes';
    }
    else{
        echo 'no';
    }
```

The result is 'no' but I can "foreach" loop through each topic.

As I unserstand, 'Foreach' accepts only array parameter but if it's a real array why is_array return "no"?

Comment: You are incorrect about `foreach`.  Anything that is [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) can be iterated over with `foreach` (as well as arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's not an array. It's a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections).

You can convert it to an array with `toArray()` method:

```
$topic = topic::where('id', $id)->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks!. So I can loop through collection because  laravel make it can?(laravel core make collections serve as iterators)

Comment: Kind of. But not Laravel, PHP does it. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Answer (score 0):

I want to Add something

In the end you will loop through weather it is an array or collection.

$topic = topic::where('id', $id)->get()->toArray();

So why you need to cast it toArray, it'll just take extra execution time to return result as an array the rather you can do same thing with collection.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth mentioning that dealing with collections can be really painless, thanks to a lot of [available methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#available-methods). Check the link form official documentation.

Then you can check against empty collection, like `isEmpty()`, etc.
Try to use as much as Laravel gives you out of the box.